# Not getting LD_LIBRARY_PATH when I run a command in PHP using system()

Tags: php, c++, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, system

I am running an in build C++ compiled file using PHP's `system()` command
But when I run this PHP code I am getting error that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` value not set.

But when I run the command in command prompt directly I am getting the result.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure PHP or set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in run time in PHP script. Similar example in c++:

```
<pre>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char szBuffer[128];
    char * psz = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    printf("Initial LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\n",psz);
    putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/somedir1");
    psz = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    sprintf(szBuffer, "%s:tmp/somedir2",psz);
    printf("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\n",psz);
    setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", szBuffer,1);
    psz = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    sprintf(szBuffer, "%s:tmp/somedir3",psz);
    printf("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\n",psz);
    setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", szBuffer,1);
    psz = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    printf("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%s\n",psz);
    return 0;
}
</pre>

output:
<pre>
Initial LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/dir1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/somedir1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/somedir1:tmp/somedir2
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/somedir1:tmp/somedir2:tmp/somedir3
</pre>
```